# Went outside the line (for went over/crossed the line)

Tags: word-usage

Someone was doing a very tiny maze, and was having a hard time staying within the lines. So she "went over/crossed the line" by accident. Do the following sentences work:

> I went outside the line. (while specifically referring to a particular line.)
>
> I went over the line.
>
> I crossed the line.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all three are fine.

(Don't know how to make this a longer or more detailed answer!)